# Updating a single divs contents and not every div with that class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="btn test-btn test-btn-1">
  <span>Content 1</span>
</a>
```

This is used multiple times on the page. The 1 at the end of the test-btn- is generated dynamically so it could be 1 or it could be 200.

When the button is clicked some AJAX runs and a class gets added to the a tag called test-btn-clicked. When it's all finished I want to update the content within the span to say something different.

Now I've tried a few ways but everytime it keeps updating the content of every button and not just the one I have clicked.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: where is the code for click handler??

Comment: Can you post the javascript too

Comment: We need to see the code which is updating the spans, that is obviously where the error lies. No doubt you have just selected `$('.test-btn')`

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Sorry for not including the JS. I'd wrote some then delete it. I've done something similar to what @MilindAnantwar had suggested below and all is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the current clicked element only, however you wont be able to access `$(this)` in ajax call as the context will be changed from clicked element to ajax call. You should define the current elements context before ajax call and then use it to update the clicked element. something like this:

```
$('.test-btn').click(function(){
 var that = this;
  $.ajax( { url: '#',success: function (result) {
        $(that).find('span').text("new span text here");
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the text to display comes necessarily from the ajax's response however I vote for your answer which is pretty neat

Comment: @willysama: i just generalized it more .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the function that triggers the ajax call:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   var that = $(this);
   that.addClass('test-btn-clicked');
   $.ajax({
     url: "test.html"
   }).done(function(data) {
      that.find('span').html(data);
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do use `this` like

```
$('.test-btn').click(function(){ //
    // your code
    $(this).find('span').text('some text');
});
```